# UTC converted to Central Europe Standard Time is 2 hours in front not 1

Tags: c#, datetime, timezone

I'm trying to understand why my date is wrong:

```
DateTime databaseUtcTime = new DateTime(2016, 8, 15, 10, 20, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
var timeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central Europe Standard Time");
var testDateTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(databaseUtcTime, timeZone);
```

`testDateTime` **outputs *15/08/2016 12:20:00* rather than *15/08/2016 11:20:00*
why is this?** Shouldn't it be 1 hour forward from UTC, not 2 ?

**EDIT----**

Thanks Jon Skeet,

If this helps anyone, i resorted to using:

```
if(testDateTime.IsDaylightSavingTime())
{
    testDateTime = testDateTime.AddHours(-1);
}
```

Albeit you not knowing the context, this could be helpful to know how to get rid of daylight saving time when running certain explicit testing on time.

Comment: It is time to turn into NodaTime. (That's a good catchphrase) : https://github.com/nodatime/nodatime

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The time zone with an ID of "Central Europe Standard Time" is just the one used by central Europe... it doesn't *really* mean standard time.

As central Europe is observing daylight savings at the moment, the offset really is UTC+2.

It's very unfortunate that the IDs used in Windows time zones are misleading like this... but the `TimeZoneInfo` implementation itself is correct.

(This isn't all that's wrong with Windows time zone names... see [Matt Johnson's](http://codeofmatt.com/2014/04/07/working-with-time-zone-names-in-net/) post on the matter for more...)

Comment: Jon Skeet, the programmer version of Jo(h)n Cena.

Comment: @Jimmyt1988 People would argue if that is a compliment since you compared him to someone who gets mixed reactions. This is not the case for Mr. Skeet.

Comment: Hahaha @user3185569 - Sorry, i should have said chuck norris.